# Recommended Java source code reading

Tags: java, open-source

Like every author needs to read a lot of classical literature to develop his own style, and like every chess player read and analyze former champions games before, I think also every programmer needs to read a lot  of high quality code.

When it comes to Java source code, what are your recommendations as "reading". Which open source projects, libraries in the past you found yet easier to grasp and easy to read but also very good examples of what "high quality" code looks like?

Comment: Hi iPhoneDeveloper, open-ended lists like this, where people take half a second to provide a one-line suggestion, might be great for a discussion forum, but [aren't a good fit for the Stack Exchange style of Q&A](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask). If you have specific high-level questions, feel free to ask those, instead.

Comment: @Mark Trapp if I can only ask "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face" then what makes this site different than Stack Overflow? I find this approach very dogmatic and rigid, you close a lot of questions where many people can get benfit, maybe you need to get a hobby :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Spring framework core source code is excellent to read. It has been recommended to me several times and I read some of it myself. Jürgen did a good job here.

Answer (score 4):

I can recommend the source code of Guice, Bob Lee et al made a lovely clean code base there

Answer (score 2):

The best source is the language inventor's own books. Search for a good book written by James Gosling. Also you can find a lot of great examples on [Java's official website.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index.html)